# How to get nested cursor from a stored procedure - Java &Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns a cursor and the cursor contains another cursor (col_ch in the bellow example). It is something like this (as I'm seeing it in my Java code)

> PROCEDURE my_proc    (
> i_val IN VARCHAR
> ,i_cont IN INTEGER
> ,o_out OUT CURSOR    );
> On my Java app I'm seeing in debug values from o_out

- id
- t_id
- **col_ch of type OracleResultSetImpl**

How can I get the value of col_ch ?
I have a simple bean that extends StoredProcedure and I've declared two input params and one output param(the cursor : o_result that when in debug shows the mentioned fields.
Thank you and appreciate the help

Comment: Open the outer cursor, read the first row from the outer cursor, read the inner cursor from the column of that row, fetch the next row from the inner cursor (I believe it should already be open, but I may be mistaken and you need to open it), read the columns, repeat and read more rows from the inner cursor until you've processed all the rows in that inner cursor, then repeat reading the next row from the outer cursor and iterating over its inner cursor until you've processed all the rows and, finally, close the outer cursor (all the inner cursors will be implicitly closed as well).

Comment: Indeed it worked and it helped me. Thank you and appreciate the quick reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open the outer cursor;
2. Read the first row from the outer cursor.
3. Read the inner cursor from the column of that row;

   - a) *I believe it should already be open, but I may be mistaken and you need to open it;*
   - b) fetch the next row from the inner cursor;
   - c) read the columns from that row of the inner cursor;
   - d) repeat and read more rows and columns from the inner cursor until you've processed all the rows in that inner cursor; then
4. Repeat reading the next row from the outer cursor and iterating over its inner cursor until you've processed all the rows; and
5. Finally, close the outer cursor (all the inner cursors will be implicitly closed as well).